# Display projected event list from existing events

Tags: sql, sql-server

The more I think about this the more complex it seems, but what I am trying to get to is a workload planning report based on work that is underway.  As a job progresses, a row is added to a database (outside of my control) with the date of the last event.  The events happen in sequence and each has a timeframe in which activity should take place.

Example tables and data below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [Cust_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustName] [varchar](50) NULL
)
INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([Cust_ID], [CustName]) VALUES (1, N'ABC Corp')
INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([Cust_ID], [CustName]) VALUES (2, N'Nuke')
INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([Cust_ID], [CustName]) VALUES (3, N'ADUDAS')
INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([Cust_ID], [CustName]) VALUES (4, N'POMA')


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventInfo](
    [Event_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NextEvent] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [NextEventDays] [int] NOT NULL
)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Received Request', 1, N'Draft Proposal', 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Draft Proposal', 2, N'Proposal Accepted', 14)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Proposal Accepted', 3, N'Project Scheduled', 14)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Project Scheduled', 4, N'Project Start', 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Project Start', 5, N'Project Complete', 30)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Project Complete', 6, N'Output Accepted', 14)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Proposal Rejected', 3, N'Draft Proposal', 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Output Rejected', 6, N'Project Start', 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EventInfo] ([Event_Name], [Sequence], [NextEvent], [NextEventDays]) VALUES (N'Output Accepted', 7, N'Complete', 0)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
    [Cust_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EventName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Received Request', CAST(N'2017-10-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Draft Proposal', CAST(N'2017-10-03T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Proposal Accepted', CAST(N'2017-10-23T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Project Scheduled', CAST(N'2017-10-23T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Project Start', CAST(N'2017-10-25T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (2, N'Received Request', CAST(N'2017-10-11T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Project Complete', CAST(N'2017-11-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Output Accepted', CAST(N'2017-11-07T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Cust_ID], [EventName], [EventDate]) VALUES (2, N'Draft Proposal', CAST(N'2017-10-15T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
```

I can get the actual events easily enough.

```
+---------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| Cust_ID | CustName |     EventName     |        EventDate        | Sequence |     NextEvent     | NextEventDays |        NextEvent        |
+---------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|       1 | ABC Corp | Received Request  | 2017-10-01 00:00:00.000 |        1 | Draft Proposal    |             5 | 2017-10-06 00:00:00.000 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Draft Proposal    | 2017-10-03 00:00:00.000 |        2 | Proposal Accepted |            14 | 2017-10-17 00:00:00.000 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Proposal Accepted | 2017-10-23 00:00:00.000 |        3 | Project Scheduled |            14 | 2017-11-06 00:00:00.000 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Project Scheduled | 2017-10-23 00:00:00.000 |        4 | Project Start     |             5 | 2017-10-28 00:00:00.000 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Project Start     | 2017-10-25 00:00:00.000 |        5 | Project Complete  |            30 | 2017-11-24 00:00:00.000 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Project Complete  | 2017-11-05 00:00:00.000 |        6 | Output Accepted   |            14 | 2017-11-19 00:00:00.000 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Output Accepted   | 2017-11-07 00:00:00.000 |        7 | Complete          |             0 | 2017-11-07 00:00:00.000 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Received Request  | 2017-10-11 00:00:00.000 |        1 | Draft Proposal    |             5 | 2017-10-16 00:00:00.000 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Draft Proposal    | 2017-10-15 00:00:00.000 |        2 | Proposal Accepted |            14 | 2017-10-29 00:00:00.000 |
+---------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

... with this query:

```
SELECT        Customers.Cust_ID, Customers.CustName, Events.EventName, Events.EventDate, EventInfo.Sequence, EventInfo.NextEvent, EventInfo.NextEventDays, Events.EventDate + EventInfo.NextEventDays AS NextEvent
FROM            Events INNER JOIN
                         EventInfo ON Events.EventName = EventInfo.Event_Name INNER JOIN
                         Customers ON Events.Cust_ID = Customers.Cust_ID
ORDER BY Customers.Cust_ID, EventInfo.Sequence
```

But what I am really after (with the available data) is more like this:

```
+---------+----------+-------------------+------------+-------------+
| Cust_ID | CustName |     EventName     | EventDate  | IsEstimated |
+---------+----------+-------------------+------------+-------------+
|       1 | ABC Corp | Received Request  | 1/10/2017  |           0 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Draft Proposal    | 3/10/2017  |           0 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Proposal Accepted | 23/10/2017 |           0 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Project Scheduled | 23/10/2017 |           0 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Project Start     | 25/10/2017 |           0 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Project Complete  | 5/11/2017  |           0 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Output Accepted   | 7/11/2017  |           0 |
|       1 | ABC Corp | Complete          | 7/11/2017  |           0 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Received Request  | 11/10/2017 |           0 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Draft Proposal    | 15/10/2017 |           0 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Proposal Accepted | 29/10/2017 |           1 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Project Scheduled | 12/11/2017 |           1 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Project Start     | 17/11/2017 |           1 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Project Complete  | 17/12/2017 |           1 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Output Accepted   | 22/12/2017 |           1 |
|       2 | Nuke     | Complete          | 22/12/2017 |           1 |
+---------+----------+-------------------+------------+-------------+
```

The idea is that we can select a date range and see what was happening / will be happening during that time.  So each job will have a row for each stage through to completion with a flag to identify if the date displayed is real or projected.

In the table above, rows with 'IsEstimated' = 0 are pulled from the Events table, as per my example query.  Rows with 'IsEstimated' have been calculated based on the last actual event for that Customer, plus the value from [EventInfo].[extEventDays].

Perhaps it is clearer with this:

```
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| Cust_ID |     EventName     |  RealDate  | EventDays |  EstDate   |
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|       2 | Received Request  | 11/10/2017 |           |            |
|       2 | Draft Proposal    | 15/10/2017 | 5.00      |            |
|       2 | Proposal Accepted |            | 14.00     | 29/10/2017 |
|       2 | Project Scheduled |            | 14.00     | 12/11/2017 |
|       2 | Project Start     |            | 5.00      | 17/11/2017 |
|       2 | Project Complete  |            | 30.00     | 17/12/2017 |
|       2 | Output Accepted   |            | 14.00     | 22/12/2017 |
|       2 | Complete          |            | 0.00      | 22/12/2017 |
|      45 |                   |            |           |            |
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I'm trying to pull the real event records and add rows for events that do not yet exist, along with the cumulative dates of all previous events, based on the 'NextEventDays' of each event.

I should also note here that I do control the structure and content of the 'EventInfo' table, and am thinking that a stored procedure updating into an intermediate table might be preferable (am using this data for SSRS reporting).

Any ideas on how to progress with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:  How awesome is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f694f/2/0)?

Comment: How do you get all events after 29/10/2017? You did not provide records with that data

Comment: Good question.  Can't believe I didn't actually spell this out explicitly.  All of the older dates (the ones with IsEstimated = 0) in the 'desired outcome' table are from rows in the database.  The rest are calculated by adding EventInfo.NextEventDays to the previous event.

I'll update the post to make that clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a temp table (or table variable, whatever) with the data you need, and then fill it and report from it. I would do something like

1. Create a temp table with Cust_ID, EventName, EventDate,
   IsEstimated
2. Fill this using the query you already have with the
   real data (setting IsEstimated to 0 for these rows)
3. Create the future estimates (See below) with IsEstimated as yes
4. Report from this table

To create the estimated data, you need to find the rows that are missing, and figure out what date they should have. You could probably do this in one query with some thought, but doing it in two steps is easier to understand

To get the missing rows, you need a list of all the missing events. You need to figure out a way to specify which events are essential - if possible, I would add another column to the eventinfo table, called something like BestPath, and set it to 1 for the events that are the ideal path. You could then ignore all the others at this point. Cross joining the event info with the Customers table gets you a list of all the steps that should be taken on the ideal path.

However, you've already done some of these. You can't just say don't do anything that already exists, because you might have looped back and need to do some twice, so you need to get the latest valid SeqenceNo for each customer, and then for each customer get all the steps on the best path that come after that sequence number, and insert them in the temp table. Assuming your temp table is #FullData, you need something like this

```
--Get the future rows
With EventBase as (
    Select E.Cust_ID, EI.Sequence, E.EventDate, ROW_NUMBER () over (PARTITION BY E.Cust_ID  ORDER BY E.EventDate DESC) as RowNo
    From [Events] E
        INNER JOIN EventInfo EI on EI.Event_Name = E.EventName
), LastKnownEvent as 
(
    SELECT Cust_ID, Sequence as LastSequence, EventDate
    FROM EventBase 
    WHERE RowNo = 1
), AllEvents as
(
    SELECT EI.Event_Name, EI.Sequence, EI.NextEventDays, LE.Cust_ID, LE.LastSequence, LE.EventDate
    FROM EventInfo EI
        CROSS JOIN LastKnownEvent LE
    WHERE EI.BestPath = 1
)
INSERT INTO #FullData (Cust_ID, Event_Name, Sequence, IsEstimated, LastKnownDate)
SELECT Cust_ID, Event_Name, Sequence, 1, EventDate
FROM AllEvents AE
WHERE Sequence > LastSequence;
```

Once you have that data, process the temp table and calculate the date required for each future row (get the sum of all NextEventDays for all future rows for the same customer with a lower sequence number, plus the nexteventdays for the last known event, then dateadd it to the LastknownDate), and store it in the temp table.

At that point, the temp table should have all the data you need for the report.